# Run time error 5 Invalid procedure call in macros

Tags: vba, macros, text-files

I am trying to import text file using macros but i am like getting the error 5, invalid procedure call. I have tried recording the macro and re ran but it is showing that error at the "commandtype" line. I could not find out the reason. Any help is appreciated

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\491840\Desktop\IE11 scripts link.txt", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "IE11 scripts link"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(10, 17, 21, 16)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is trying to do a process with an incompatible file type. Try removing the commmandtype line and then rerunning. Hopefully that works

Comment: Yes that worked thanks. You helped me a lot. Thank you very much